# Usual technical term for replacing a set by the set of singletons of its members?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, mathematical-writing

> What is a standard technical term in axiomatic set theory for the operation which sends a given set $A$ to the set $A':=\{\{a\}\colon a\in A\}$?

(Replacement implies that $A'$ is a set.)

Some pointers to relevant places in the literature would also be appreciated, especially if (0) the treatments emphasize large infinite sets and (1) take a point of view on this operation within a larger theoretical context, possibly characterizing it as an endofunctor of $\textsf{Sets}$ having certain properties. (It appears, though it is not the motivation for this question, that $A=\emptyset$ is its only fixed point.)

In case of epistemic answers being in short supply, deontic answers giving opinions how this operation *ought* to be called and denoted are also appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, _discrete partition_ for $A\mapsto \{\{a\}\colon a\in A\}$ and _indiscrete partition_ for $A\mapsto \{A\}$ appears the most sensible pair of technical terms for this, in tune with other usages in contemporary measure theory and topology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$A'$ is the [discrete partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153276/a-formal-name-for-smallest-and-largest-partition) of $A$.

That is, we think of it as a partition of $A$ induced by the finest equivalence relation, the identity relation.

Comment: I believe the OP is after the name of the *operation* that sends a set to its discrete partition.

Comment: Well the operation that sends a set to its power set is called "power set" I suppose, so the operation here would be "discrete partition".

Comment: It's not just any partition, it's a very fine partition! :)